# Powershell remove two line before a match of string

Tags: powershell

I have `file.txt` that has content like this with empty line in between:

```
TESTING CONNECTION TO SERVER 1.1.1.1

COULD NOT CONNECT TO SERVER 

TESTING CONNECTION TO SERVER 1.2.111.11

CONNECTION TO SERVER SUCCESSFUL

TESTING CONNECTION TO SERVER 12.1.1211.1

COULD NOT CONNECT TO SERVER
```

The main aim is to remove the IP address or its line from the file which are not able to connect. If the string matches like '**COULD NOT CONNECT**' then the **ip address** or its line before has to be removed using PowerShell script.

```
$data = foreach($line in Get-Content $env:TEMP\file.txt)
    {
   
    if($line -like '*COULD NOT CONNECT*')
        {
          
          $linenumber = Get-Content $env:TEMP\file.txt | select-string 'COULD NOT CONNECT' | Select-Object LineNumber
          $b = 2
          foreach($lines in $linenumber
          $lineno=$lines.LineNumber - $b
          write-host $lineno 
          
          #logic 1
          $content = Get-Content $env:TEMP\file.txt
          $content | Skip -Index $lineno > $env:TEMP\OUTPUT_refined.txt


        #logic 2
          Get-Content $env:TEMP\file.txt | 
          Where-Object ReadCount -ne $lineno |
          Set-Content -Encoding Utf8 $env:TEMP\file.txt -Force
        #logic 3
        $file = "$env:TEMP\file.txt"
        $outFile = [IO.File]::CreateText("$env:TEMP\OUTPUT_refined.txt")
        $lineNo = 0
        try {
          foreach ($line in [IO.File]::ReadLines("$env:TEMP\file.txt")) {
            if (++$lineNo -eq $lineno) { continue }
            $outFile.WriteLine($line)
          }
        } finally {
          $outFile.Dispose()
        }
        }
    }  
        
    else
        {
            $line
   }         
}
    $data | Set-Content $env:TEMP\file.txt -Force
```

Try attempts with various logics based on calculating line numbers and creating new file with refined content.

After removing the contents either I need it can be same file or we can use Set-Content and create a new file anything is fine. Experts help needed. Thanks.

Comment: If you have any code attempts that are not working please post them.  We are here to help you fix your code.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, Edited the question with attempts done so far, none worked.

Comment: ist not clear, do you want to remove all the 3 lines or just the line with the ip. and you want to resave the file with same structure?

Answer (score 1):

this code removes the 3 lines: i am using directly the regex of C#

```
$data = Get-Content -Path file.txt - raw

#select multiline option for regex -> 
# so you can work with `r`n  (line of feed, new line) 
$option = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline 

$pattern = [regex]::new("TESTING.+?`r?`n`r?`nCOULD NOT CONNECT.+?`r?`n", $option)

$data = $pattern.Replace($data, "")

$data | Set-Content -Path newfile.txt -Force
```

---

```
TESTING.+?`r?`n`r?`nCOULD NOT CONNECT.+?`r?`n
```

i am searching all lines beginning by `TESTING` and finishing by `2 Endoflines` (following the text editor  endofline is `'r'n` or `'n` so `'r?` means 0 or 1 occurence) and following by `COULD NOT CONNECT` then `end of this line`.

that is the selection of 3 lines

Comment: It worked and resulted the expected output. Could you please explain the two line of logic to understand how this is actually works,

$option = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline 

$pattern = [regex]::new("TESTING.+?`r?`n`r?`nCOULD NOT CONNECT.+?`r?`n", $option)

Comment: i put explanation in the answer.